# What are open problems in computer science?

Tags: natural-language-processing, computational-linguistics, open-problem

I should prepare some paper for a colloquium (kinda student-task) and it should cover the following points:

(1) at least one notable discovery in theoretical informatics (or computer science)

(2) at least one open problems in theoretical informatics

(3) an example of short notable proof of some result in theoretical informatics

Can you draw some examples of it? Or some sources?

I would like that it was related with computational linguistics or natural language processing.

Thank you